# How to deploy Docker image on EC2 instance using codedeploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I am pushing a Docker image to ECR repo using the buildspec.yml file. This is what my buildspec.yml look like:

```
version: 0.2
 
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 16       
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR.....
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <account-id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
      - REPOSITORY_URI=<account-id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/vuejs
      - IMAGE_TAG=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
  build:
    commands:
      - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG .
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Pushing image now...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - printf '[{"name":"vuejs","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
artifacts:
    files: 
      - imagedefinitions.json
      - appspec.yml
```

and this is my appspec.yml file:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /
```

Now my pipeline ( codepipeline ) passes but how can I configure my appspec.yml file to deploy Docker container on my EC2 instance?

Comment: You have to write your scripts for code-deploy to execute. Have to done that or at least even attempted?

Comment: You aren't using ECS for this, correct? Just a plain EC2 instance? If so, you'll have to write a script for CodeDeploy to run on the EC2 instance that does the work of pulling the image from ECR and running the appropriate `docker` command to start a container with that image.

Comment: @Marcin Yes, i eventually moved to doing that. Couldn't think of any other way.

Comment: @MarkB You're right, i'm using a plain EC2 instance. No ECS for that and you and marcin are right, i had to use a script eventually. I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: You would have to use ECS to avoid scripting that. But in general, CI/CD platforms are just things for running a sequence of scripts.

Comment: Sweet. Thank you both for looking into it.